# Google sheets SUMIF by Name and Date

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

I need some help regarding Google sheets and SUMIF instruction.

I have a table where I collect some inputs from a form. I contains a date, name and value.
Now I want to summarize by the name and date. Means person x spends € in month April. Or person y spends € in this month.
My approach was this:

```
=SUMIFs(Formularantworten!B2:B; Formularantworten!E2:E; "x"; Month(Formularantworten!C2:C); Month(now()))
```

But as it seems, sheets can't handle dates within SUMIF.
Plan is to have a table, where the sum for each person and month is noted and a filed where you can see the current month.

Do anybody has a idea to solve this?

Thanks in advance.
Kai

Comment: Why not doing it by a pivot table?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Here you will find the table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_iDzvPNeY4dLvcIkP3nNfE5o1LZO2mPqGqCMbjqFJO0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to use an array formula to use the month function on all values in the range `C2:C`:

`=SUMIFs(Formularantworten!B2:B; Formularantworten!E2:E; "Sabi"; Arrayformula(Month(Formularantworten!C2:C)); Month(now()))`

Reference:

- [Arrayformula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)